# Pandas DataFrame reindex to nearest

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've added a "Non-Uniform Column Sampling" case below.

### Uniform Column Sampling

Imagine the following data set:

```
         x    y
t              
0.010  1.0  NaN
0.015  NaN  5.0
0.022  3.0  NaN
0.023  NaN  4.0
0.031  5.0  NaN
0.032  NaN  7.0
```

The objective is to *reindex* this data to a common sampling interval and associate the closest sample points.  Namely, the return:

```
         x    y
t              
0.01  1.0  5.0
0.02  3.0  4.0
0.03  5.0  7.0
```

I attempt this using the pandas DataFrame.reindex method.  However, it doesn't appear to work.  Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_dict = {'t':[0.01  , 0.015 , 0.022 , 0.023 , 0.031 , 0.032],
             'x':[   1  , np.nan, 3     , np.nan, 5     , np.nan],
             'y':[np.nan, 5     , np.nan, 4     , np.nan, 7] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df.set_index('t', inplace=True)
df.reindex([0.01, 0.02, 0.03], method='nearest', tolerance=0.01)
```

The result is:

```
        x   y
t            
0.01  1.0 NaN
0.02  3.0 NaN
0.03  5.0 NaN
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the intended use case for the *reindex* method
2. How can this be achieved?

### Non-Uniform Column Sampling

Imagine this data set:

```
         x    y
t              
0.010  1.0  NaN
0.022  3.0  NaN
0.023  NaN  5.0
0.031  5.0  NaN
0.039  NaN  7.0
0.041  4.0  NaN
```

In this case the sampling frequency for the columns are indeed different but we would like to re-index them to a common timescale.  How can a *reindex* be applied to get the following:

```
         x    y
t              
0.010  1.0  NaN
0.020  3.0  5.0
0.030  5.0  NaN
0.040  4.0  7.0
```

Same two questions.

Comment: You have tolerance=0.01, that is why y is nan

Comment: @Wen, The problem persists regardless of tolerance value.  Actually, I believe the expected utility is to first apply a "fillna()" and then do the "reindex()".  What is happening now is that it is re-indexing but finding the nearest value is a NAN.  But if you "fillna()" first, you lose the any variable sampling rate between columns 'x' and 'y' (although this example doesn't illustrate that).

Comment: @Hamid In your updated example, the y-column for `0.03` has a value within tolerance, namely `0.023 -> 5.0`, so why do you expect NaN after reindexing?

Comment: @a_guest, I think because the output of `y` should only actually be reindexed on `[0.02, 0.04]`, and the `NaN` is the result of concatenating the `DataFrames` back together.

Comment: @ALollz That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the re-indexing per column, dropping the NaNs beforehand, and then just stick the pieces back together:

```
t = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03]
df2 = pd.concat(
    map(lambda c: df[c].dropna().reindex(t, method='nearest', tolerance=0.01),
        df.columns),
    axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `NaN` values are the closest matches in the `y` column so it is choosing them. You could first interpolate to fill the `NaN` values appropriately and then reindex.

```
df.interpolate(method='nearest').ffill().bfill().reindex([0.01, 0.02, 0.03], method='nearest')

        x    y
t             
0.01  1.0  5.0
0.02  3.0  4.0
0.03  5.0  7.0
```

Comment: Thank you!  How about if 'x' and 'y' different sampling rates?  For example, 'x' was sampled every 0.01 time intervals but 'y' existed every '0.02' intervals?  Perhaps I'll update the question.

Comment: I've updated the question with a second example data set where the sampling intervals were different.  I don't think the same solution would work.  As soon as the filling methods are applied we lose the original sampling intervals for the 'y' column.

Comment: @Hamid, I see. In that case, I think you should use the solution provided by @a_guest. You simply need to change `t` to be a dictionary, with the indices specified for each column.